# Spring Tool Suiteの「Maven install」でエラーになってしまう

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, maven

以下の手順で環境を用意しました。

(1)STS導入
　http://spring.io/tools/sts
　spring-tool-suite-3.9.2.RELEASE-e4.7.2-win32-x86_64.zipをダウンロードし、C直下で解凍
　（C:\sts-bundle）
(2)日本語化
　http://mergedoc.osdn.jp/
　pleiades-win.zipをダウンロードして実施
(3)環境設定
　https://www.javadrive.jp/start/install/index4.html

コマンドプロンプトで以下を確認できています。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

以下の手順でプロジェクトを追加しました。
(1)ファイル->新規作成->springスタータ・プロジェクトを選択
(2)以下の内容でTestAppプロジェクト作成
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
(3)ウインドウ->設定->Java->インストール済みのJREを確認
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
(4)パッケージエクスプローラの「TestApp」を選択し、右クリック->実行->Maven clean実施
　コンソールで以下のログを確認。
　[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
(5)パッケージエクスプローラの「TestApp」を選択し、右クリック->実行->Maven installを実施
　コンソールでエラー
　[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project TestApp: Compilation failure
　[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
　[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Huxz.png)

◆JDKのパスや環境設定が誤っているのかと思い見ているのですが、
　上記記載どおり、あっているように思うのですが、何か見落としやおかしな設定などありますでしょうか？
少し気になったのが、maven installやmaven clearをした場合に
コンソールの上のほうに下記のように表示されているところです。（キャプチャを張っています）
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_92\bin\javaw.exe
jdkを指定しているので、\jdk1.8.0_92\bin\javaw.exeとなるのではと思ったのですが…

Comment: 参考になりそうなもの：https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655184/no-compiler-is-provided-in-this-environment-perhaps-you-are-running-on-a-jre-ra

Comment: STS上で[ローカルターミナル](https://qiita.com/kazuki43zoo/items/9053a1e246dd6daca967#%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AB%E3%83%AB%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%83%9F%E3%83%8A%E3%83%AB%E3%82%92%E9%96%8B%E3%81%8F)を開いて ([参考図](https://camo.qiitausercontent.com/e6e8ca6d255122a9f01e29f8a2c668b3390f7b6f/68747470733a2f2f71696974612d696d6167652d73746f72652e73332e616d617a6f6e6177732e636f6d2f302f3131373331332f33336561323435642d393130622d396637642d613166342d6532326330333861613833352e706e67))、そこで `javac -version` コマンドを実行するとどうなるでしょうか。バージョン表記が出力されないのであればpathの設定が間違っていると考えられます。どのように(どこで)`JAVA_HOME`及び`PATH`の設定を行ったのか追記されると原因の特定につながるかと。

Comment: 設定 > Maven > インストール で使用しているMavenのバージョンとパスが分かります。そのパスに移動(`cd`)して、`mvn -version`コマンド実行したら、どのJavaを使っているか分かります。

Comment: yukihaneさま　コメントありがとうございます。レスが遅くなり申し訳ありません。
STS上でターミナルを開けることを初めて知りました。勉強になります。
(3)環境設定　のサイトのJAVA_HOMEの設定がbinまで設定するようになっており、
気づき、修正したのですがその段階ではMaven Installはエラーになっていたのですが、
PC再起動後に確認すると、エラーがでないことを確認できました！（PC再起動がよかったのか、STS再起動がよかったのかはわかりませんが…）

Comment: Kohei TAMURAさま
MavenのバージョンとパスについてSTSでの確認方法を知りませんでした。勉強になりました。ありがとうございます。